# Game Physics - Not very life-like

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, physics, game-physics

In a simple game (cocos2d) I have a made a small physics engine to move a sprite so that it can jump and stand on platforms ect.

To update the position (vertical movement) I use basic kinematics equations in each update:

- position = oldPosition + velocity(delta) +1/2(gravity)(delta)^2
- velocity = oldVelocity + (gravity)(delta)

For some reason the game doesn't seem very life-like. It seems to take a long time near the top of an arc, despite how great I make gravity. If I want my sprite to jump the same height, but decelerate and accelerate more quickly, but still jump just as high as before, how should I do that? I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is you have made a mistake with your physics! But that is okay, because it is an easy fix.

When calling your update method on your sprite's position, you should first set the acceleration. I assume gravity is a constant for this game, and so you only need to set it once. (-9.81, or something similar.)

You then want to update the velocity of the character in the y direction by velocity = old_velocity + acceleration * time.

After doing this you then update the position in a similar way: position = old_position + velocity * time.

The equation you are using to update the position is valid only if delta is the total elapsed time, and not a time-step! (I have assumed delta is a time step, because that's how physics games are usually programmed.)

I hope this helps! If you want to know more, check out suvat equations, you will see that you can compute a final position if you know an initial velocity and a constant acceleration, where as your game will have a velocity that varies when you do jumping and collisions, and so it does not surprise that it isn't realistic! Any more questions, just comment and I will try to help you further.

EDIT: I reprogrammed exactly what you have done here with some boxes drawn using OpenGL. Your method of updating the position does not seem to work. The boxes only seem to fall correctly if the `dt` or timestep is 1.0d, and I am not sure why. Then when they collide with something, they stop all together instead of bouncing. I am not sure exactly why.

However, I also have another box on the screen which uses the physics I described:
`v = u + a*t` and `s = s_last + v*t`
The box falls exactly as expected and bounces correctly. Due to a simplification, energy is lost in the bouncing.

Comment: See the second kinematics equation: http://physics.info/kinematics-calculus/ My equation is the same.

Comment: Yes it is, but unfortunately it is not valid for this type of work.

Comment: Do you understand what that equation calculates? Would it help if I explain it?

Comment: updating the velocity and moving the object by dt * newSpeed on each update as Edward says, is indeed a more convenient way to implement simple psysics. The calculation with the suvat formulae would be needed to -predict- the total travel, or the initial velocity needed for a targeted jump (e.g make a boss jump and land over the player).

Comment: But the rest of what you say is not  relevant. As you say, you tried the suvat equation in a different environment and you are not sure why it didn't work. This doesn't mean that the equation is wrong. You can use it as long as the acceleration is constant (and gravity is constant). It should work, and it actually really does as the asker says. Chances are that you didn't implement it right

Comment: Edward is correct. Your forumula, `y = y0 + v0y*t + 1/2*g*t^2`, is the formula for total distance travelled. You can not use that in a time step. You need to use the differential of this formula, `dy = v0y*dt + g*t*dt`. This is a property of calculus. Look up "total derivative". Basically, for any function f(t), `df = (df/dt) * dt` where `(df/dt)` is the partial derivative of the function with respect to `t`.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. If you're using the same (initial) speed on the suvat formula, it will be wrong. I thought that you were updating it with the new speed in each timestep. In any case, I've already agreed that the suvat formula should be used to calculate total distance. For time steps usage it's an overkill

Comment: Ed Bird says: Basically if you add an impulse to an object where the position is computed by this formula it will "go wrong". Reason is: An impulse is a sudden change in velocity. This is used for "jumping" and other such collisions. So you are using a formula, which was integrated over time of an original function. That original function is no longer smooth (as in described by a mathematical formula), and therefore no longer integrable.

Basically do real-time numerical integration not mathematical integration. I haven't explained myself very well but you should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer to try out Box2d or Chipmunk physics engines in your cocos2d-iphone game for a more life-like effect. Plus, they're relatively easy to implement.

No need to make your own physics system - remember to let the technology work for you ;D

Comment: I did try to implement Box2d. It is a really light-weight and simple game it doesn't need that large a physics engine. I find that multiplying the new velocity by a coefficient of 5 or so helps.

Comment: @bluestunt: I understand, but I'm sure that countless simple games that involve things like pong have used this kind of "overkill" engine. It just makes your life easier. Better to have spare power than lack any! Plus, using Box2d or Chipmunk doesn't really imply a more complex configuration - if all you need are basic functions, then all you will get are basic configurations.

Comment: There is no need to implement a physics engine, changing your equation so that it is correct will do the trick. PS: I edited my answer now that I have written a program using your equation and the ones I use. I am quite confused by the results, because I have been thinking about this for too long now, but the long story short is use: `v = v_last + accel * timestep` to get new y-velocity, then use: `y = y_last + v * timestep` to get new y position.